# Angular (4): password match validator not working

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I am trying to write my first custom validator for Angular (4). I think I set everything up correctly, but something is missing. The validator simply doesn't work. It doesn't show any errors or anything.

Here is the validator:

```
export class PasswordValidator {
  static matchPassword(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const password = control.get('password').value;
    const passwordConfirmation = control.get('passwordConfirmation').value;
    if (password != passwordConfirmation) {
      console.log('passwords did not match');
      control.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({matchPassword: true})
    } else {
      console.log('successfully matched');
      return null
    }
  }
}
```

This is the validation directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[passwordDomain][ngModel]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useValue: PasswordValidator,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class PasswordValidationDirective {

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

And this is the html code where this validator is used:

```
<input mdInput
       type="password"
       required
       ngModel name="passwordConfirmation"
       #passwordConfirmation="ngModel"
       passwordDomain
       placeholder="{{'PASSWORD_RECOVERY.PASSWORD_CONFIRMATION' | translate}}">
       <md-error *ngIf="passwordConfirmation.touched && passwordConfirmation.invalid">
                <span *ngIf="passwordConfirmation.errors?.matchPassword">
                      {{'PASSWORD_RECOVERY.MATCH' | translate}}
                </span>
       </md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Read the return type of the method. It's sypposed to return ValidationErrors, or null if there is no error. Your method returns null if there is no error, and doesn't return anything if there is one. Instead, it updates the errors of one of the controls, which it shouldn't do. In addition, this validator expects a FormGroup as argument, containing two controls password and passwordConfirmation. But you're adding the directive on an input (i.e. on a single FormControl).

Comment: Oh, and also, you're passing a class instead of passing the validation directive in the directive decorator. And your directive doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JBNizet can you please compose an answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The comments I already gave you, + the explanations in the documentation (https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) should help you already.

Comment: There is no need to be rude. I wanted to have a full answer and accept it as per correct flow of this community.

Comment: @JBNizet any reason for the DV i got if, i am not sure about who but is that wtrong

Comment: @DenissM. where have I been rude?

Comment: @JBNizet I have made the adjustments you've mentioned and nothing changed.